# Retrieving rows based on time in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which includes two columns `StartTime` and `EndTime` of type `Time` besides others. I want to retrieve rows for which `StartTime` and `EndTime` conflicts with a certain input time range.

Let's say the table contains these rows:

```
ID Status StartTime EndTime
-- ------ --------- --------
0     0   08:00:00  08:50:00
1     1   08:50:00  09:40:00
```

And I want to have which conflicts with the range `08:00:00` - `08:40:00`. It should return the first row.

I'm trying to do it as:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE
StartTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:40:00'
OR
EndTime BETWEEN '08:40:00' AND '08:40:00'
```

I shall be very very thankful if someone solve my this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree with [@John Dewey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771810/297408), if you want to find ranges conflicting with a specific range, your condition seems incomplete, because, as John has correctly pointed out, if the specified range is entirely falls between the bounds of some range in your table, the corresponding row will not match your condition.

But rather than making your condition more complex, you could in fact make it simpler, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE StartTime <= '08:40:00'
  AND EndTime   >= '08:00:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this never actually happens, but just to be thorough, I would also check for conflicts where the range '08:00:00' AND '08:40:00' fall entirely between StartTime and EndTime, e.g. StartTime = 07:30:00 and EndTime = 09:00:00:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (
    StartTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:40:00'
    OR
    EndTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:40:00'
    OR
    '08:00:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime
    OR
    '08:40:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE 
   StartTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:40:00' 
OR EndTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:40:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second clause should be `EndTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:40:00'`.  Otherwise, what you have should work.

Answer (score 0):

**To return only the first record**, use `TOP` and **be sure** to include `ORDER BY` when using `TOP`  *to determine what is the 'first'* record.  The `union` is because I am assuming that the 'first' value could be determined by either starttime or endtime. Notice `ORDER BY` has to be used in the subqueries, anytime you use `TOP`, otherwise you will get unexpected results.

```
SELECT TOP(1)[Status],StartTime,EndTime 
FROM (
      SELECT TOP(1) [Status],StartTime,EndTime,StartTime AS TEST
      FROM dbo.MyTable
      WHERE StartTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:40:00'
      ORDER BY StartTime DESC 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT TOP(1) [Status],StartTime,EndTime,EndTime AS TEST
      FROM dbo.MyTable
      WHERE
      EndTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:40:00'
      ORDER BY EndTime DESC 
) x
ORDER BY TEST DESC
```

**If 'first' record should only determined by one value, for example starttime, just do this:**

```
SELECT TOP(1) [Status],StartTime,EndTime 
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE StartTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:40:00'
OR EndTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:40:00'
ORDER BY StartTime DESC
```